flow_from_directory returns no image eventhough os.listdir() gives the count of files present correct
I am new to DL in terms of Image tasks.  Here is the snippet I am using for Data generators for training and testing
classes = ['glioma', 'meningioma', 'pituitary', 'notumor']

train_dirs = [
    'Data/Training/glioma',
    'Data/Training/glioma',  
    'Data/Training/meningioma',
    'Data/Training/pituitary',
    'Data/Training/notumor'
]

test_dirs = [
    'Data/Testing/glioma',
    'Data/Testing/meningioma',
    'Data/Testing/pituitary',
    'Data/Testing/notumor'
]

print([len(os.listdir(train_dir)) for train_dir in train_dirs])


def get_data_generators(train_dirs, test_dirs, target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=32):
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0 / 255.0)
    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0 / 255.0)

    train_generators = []
    for train_dir in train_dirs:
        print(f"Loading training data from: {train_dir}")
        train_gen = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            train_dir,
            target_size=target_size,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            class_mode='categorical',
            shuffle=True
        )
        train_generators.append(train_gen)


    test_generators = []
    for test_dir in test_dirs:
        print(f"Loading testing data from: {test_dir}")
        test_gen = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            test_dir,
            target_size=target_size,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            class_mode='categorical',
            shuffle=False
        )
        test_generators.append(test_gen)

    return train_generators, test_generators


train_generators, test_generators = get_data_generators(train_dirs, test_dirs)

And the Output is
[1321, 1321, 1339, 1457, 1595]
Loading training data from: Data/Training/glioma
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
Loading training data from: Data/Training/glioma
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
Loading training data from: Data/Training/meningioma
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
Loading training data from: Data/Training/pituitary
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
Loading training data from: Data/Training/notumor
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
Loading testing data from: Data/Testing/glioma
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
Loading testing data from: Data/Testing/meningioma
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
Loading testing data from: Data/Testing/pituitary
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
Loading testing data from: Data/Testing/notumor
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.

I have checked the folder structure from keras blog     and My structure matches the same with valid file extention as jpg. What can be the possible mistake here , I want to learn , Thanks in advance .

You don't need to loop inside the folder, it will automatically pick the data and labels i.e. classes based on inner folder names.
def get_data_generators(train_dir, test_dir, target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=32):
    
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0 / 255.0)
    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0 / 255.0)

    # Create the training data generator
    print(f"Loading training data from: {train_dir}")
    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,
        target_size=target_size,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        shuffle=True
    )

    # Create the testing data generator
    print(f"Loading testing data from: {test_dir}")
    test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        test_dir,
        target_size=target_size,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        shuffle=False
    )

    return train_generator, test_generator


train_dir = Data/Training
test_dir = Data/Testing

Then, you can train the model. Please define steps_per_epochs correctly.
model.fit_generator(train_generator,epochs=2)

